# Java document printing in Windows

Tags: java, windows, printing, printer-control-language, network-printers

I am doing a project which will finally print a pdf file or doc file to the printer as "another user". But now I stuck on how to print document in Java.

I know there is a pdf renderer in java, developed by sun, which can convert pdf to pcl file.

After the conversion, I want to print the pcl file to remote printers.
My previous way is "copy /b filename \printserver\printer", however, this approach actually is too lowlevel and cannot even display the document name, and sometime is not working.

I wonder is there a better approach of java to send the PCL file to print server, where the server can actually detect the document name and host name(which I want to specify in the program, not the original one). This one is really driving me crazy...Thanks!

Comment: For me now, the most difficult part is how to let the equitrac print server detect the "fake" username - I want to print as a different user, or send-to print.

Comment: programs like equitrac can often use PJL commands or other details in the print file -- you might look there.  I'm not much of a Java guy but you could look to this for some ideas: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into java print service? 
You can find some useful code here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jps/spec/printing.fm2.html

Comment: Yes. I tried that one, and it works. Also I wonder can I change the printjobAttributes to changed the default originating username and document name, especially the username.